# 404 On All Links After Ruby On Rails & VueJS Project Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I've just deployed my first project (Ruby on Rails backend to Heroku and VueJS frontend to Netlify). I have successfully been able to get the homepage to appear and have Netlify communicate with my Heroku database, but my frontend links are all broken and display a 404 error. I have an index.html file which seems to work, as I can successfully display my homepage, but any time I try to follow links (on my navbar, for example), I always get a 404 error.

Comment: Have you configured push state routing on netlify? See e.g. https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response – I do have a _redirects file in which I redirect to index.html. Do I have to redirect for each and every url that I have? I'm not 100% sure how all of this works.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. If the frontend is deployed on netlify the rails bit is irrelevant.

Comment: Please re-read the linked help and [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of reading, I realized I was missing my _redirects file. Once I added this, everything is working properly. Thank you to all of those who helped.